# PHP Doctrine: Custom nested set?

Tags: php, doctrine, hierarchical-data

Is it possible to have nested set capabilities in this somewhat custom setup?

Consider these 4 tables:

> 1. **Object**:          (`oid`, `name`) contains: [1, 'Licence'] and [2, 'Exemption']
> 2. **Licence**:        (`lid`, `name`)
> 3. **Exemption**:    (`eid`, `name`)
> 4. **Cost**:             (`oid`, `oid_ref`, `cost_oid`, `cost_oid_ref`)

For:
**P** = Licence with `lid` [1]
**R** = Exemption with `eid` [2]

i can say "object **P** is a *parent* to object **R**" if the following Cost record exists:

`[oid: 2
oid_ref: 2
cost_oid: 1
cost_oid_ref: 1]`

I understand that this creates somesort of 'conditional foreign key' relation which I need to define in code. **Is it possible to have the nested set loaded with these conditions?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying in some way using [column_aggregation inheritance](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/inheritance#column-aggregation), but I have a gut feeling it's not gonna work... :S